# Как сравнить качество изображений?

Tags: php, алгоритм, изображения

У меня есть набор изображений.

Парсером через гугловский поиск по изображениям вытаскиваю все идентичные фото. У этих фото разный размер и качество.

Мне нужно определить изображение с наилучшим качеством.

Например: Есть 2 одинаковых изображения `700x700` px.
У одного оригинальный размер `700x700`px.
Другое было получено путем ресайза из изображения `300x300` px.
Естественно, качество у второго меньше.

Я пока придумал только ресайзить все фото до одного разрешения и сравнивать их размеры.

Есть ли лучший способ организовать сравнение?

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, здесь вместо "качества изображения" (субъективного понятия) лучше говорить об "объёме информации". Ведь чем больше информации в картинке (и мы говорим не о размере файла), тем оно "качественнее" с точки зрения Вашего определения (не получено "путём ресайза" и т.д.).

Если принять эту терминологию, то можно попробовать использовать характеристику "количество информации в изображении", определяемую как сумму модулей разностей компонент цветов для всех пар соседних пикселов.

Для простоты давайте пока считать, что имеет смысл сравнивать эти характеристики только для изображений одного размера.

Пример:

Есть исходная картинка размером 6x3 пикселова:

```
123456
321654
123456
```

А есть её уменьшенный вариант размером 2x1 (взяли усреднение по обоим квадратикам 3x3:

```
25
```

Чтобы понять, какая картинка лучше, их надо привести к одному размеру (т.е. растянуть вторую, не используя никаких алгоритмов сглаживания). Получим такой результат

```
222555
222555
222555
```

Теперь насчитаем наши характеристики для первой картинки и для растянутой второй картинки: получаем значения `15+8` и `9+0`, соответственно (здесь 15 и 9 - это сумма модулей разностей по горизонтальной оси, а 8 и 0 - то же самое по вертикальной оси). Это означает, что в первой картинке информации гораздо больше (в чём мы не сомневались).

Немного подумав, можно прийти к пониманию, что растягивать вторую картинку не было необходимости, а достаточно правильным образом учитывать это растяжение при вычислении характеристики. Но это уже этап оптимизации, а на стадии прототипа я бы рекомендовал тренировать алгоритм сравнением изображений одного размера.

Comment: Мое предположение к этому и сводилось, спасибо за более глубокий ответ. А по поводу оптимизации путем растяжение особенно пригодилось, ведь проще посчитать коэффициент разности размера изображений и сравнить вес каждого фото с учетом этого коэффициента.

Comment: @РоманМальцев , говоря "вес", Вы подразумеваете "количество информации" или размер файла? Кстати, вообще говоря, это близкие характеристики, если сохранять изображения в lossless формате (как png, например). Альтернативный вариант: сохранять в bmp, но паковать zip-ом, например.

Comment: Под весом я подразумевал размер изображения. Я думаю что эти величины: размер файла и количество информации - тождественные, ну или близко к тому. Если сравнивая не вес, а количество информации, будет более точно, то как это значение получить средствами php?

Comment: До вашего ответа я думал что эти величины - одно и то же. Ведь единица измерения bit в обоих случаях.

Comment: Размер файла зависит от его формата: одно и то же изображение будет иметь очень разные размеры, если сохранить его в форматах bmp и png, например. Опять же, если использовать сжатие с потерями (jpg), то можно достичь очень малого объёма файла даже для очень больших и сложных изображений. Средствами php это можно делать тем же способом, что и средствами других языков: перегнать картинку в трёхмерный массив (ширина х высота х 3, где 3 - это количество компонент цветов), а потом что-нибудь посчитать на этом массиве (например, как я предложил, но лучше ещё поэкспериментировать).

Comment: Самый простой способ - сравнивать размеры файлов. Изображение с меньшим количеством информации сжимается лучше.

Comment: Но артефакты jpg будут имитировать большее количество информации?

Comment: @Qwertiy, совершенно верно! И не факт, что даже живой человек всегда сможет отличить истинные детали фотографии от дефектов компрессии, поэтому едва ли удастся создать абсолютно надёжный алгоритм. Но приблизиться к нему можно. Кстати, артефакты масштабирования тоже могут неожиданно много информации в картинку добавить (зависит от метода масштабирования).